# how to get Jquery final countdown plugin to stop at certain time of the day?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get Jquery Final Countdown to stop at a certain time of day? I would like to stop at 3:00pm of this day.

```
$('.clock').countdown('2015/09/4', function(event) {

   //display clock in : w/d/hr/min/sec format
   var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
   + '<span>%w</span> weeks '
   + '<span>%d</span> days '
   + '<span>%H</span> hr '
   + '<span>%M</span> min '
   + '<span>%S</span> sec'));
```

Comment: which plugin are you using ?

Comment: [link] (http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#introduction), you can give time in hh:mm:ss format after date in the same string.

So, for 3 pm, the finalDate would be '2015/09/4 15:00:00'

Script:

```
$('.clock').countdown('2015/09/4 15:00:00', function(event) {

   //display clock in : w/d/hr/min/sec format
   var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
   + '<span>%w</span> weeks '
   + '<span>%d</span> days '
   + '<span>%H</span> hr '
   + '<span>%M</span> min '
   + '<span>%S</span> sec'));
});
```